# Reading XML in classic ASP

Tags: xml, asp-classic

I am trying to extract some XML into classic ASP for an old site.

I can make it work for one example but not another. I am wondering if anybody can let me know what I need to do to get them both running. Thanks in advance.

Working example

```
Dim o2, oXML2
Set oXML2 = Server.CreateObject("Msxml2.DOMDocument.6.0")
Set o2 = Server.CreateObject("Msxml2.ServerXMLHTTP.6.0")
o2.open "GET", "https://api.eveonline.com/eve/CharacterID.xml.aspx?names=BorisKarlov", False
o2.send


xml2 = o2.responseText
oXML2.LoadXML xml2

response.Write oXML2.selectSingleNode("//currentTime").Text
```

Failing example

```
Dim o, oXML
Set oXML = Server.CreateObject("Msxml2.DOMDocument.6.0")
Set o = Server.CreateObject("Msxml2.ServerXMLHTTP.6.0")
o.open "GET", "http://api.freelancer.com/User/Properties.xml?id=sulung81", False
o.send

xml = o.responseText
oXML.LoadXML xml

response.Write oXML.selectSingleNode("//url").Text
```

Comment: And, how does it not work? What is what you get? What do you think you should get? Is there any error?

Comment: Thanks so much for you help on this. I am getting the error: msxml6.dll error '80004005'
Attempt to modify a read-only node.
relating to the line:
oXML.setProperty "SelectionNamespaces", "xmlns:fl='http://api.freelancer.com/schemas/xml-0.1'"

Answer (score 1):

The failing example has an XML namespace set (`xmlns="http://api.freelancer.com/schemas/xml-0.1"`).

All elements in this file are in that namespace. You must use it when you select nodes.

```
Dim oXML, node
Set oXML = Server.CreateObject("Msxml2.DOMDocument.6.0")

oXML.load "http://api.freelancer.com/User/Properties.xml?id=sulung81"
oXML.setProperty "SelectionNamespaces", "xmlns:fl='http://api.freelancer.com/schemas/xml-0.1'"

Set node = oXML.selectSingleNode("/fl:profile/fl:url")

If Not node Is Nothing
    Response.Write node.Text
End If
```

Notes

- You can use [the `.load()` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms762722%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to load a file directly from an URL. There is no need for an extra `ServerXMLHTTP` object.
- Always check the result of `selectSingleNode()` - it might be `Nothing`.
- You should test for [parse errors](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms756041%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), too.
- You must use a namespace prefix, even if the document does not use one. You can choose whatever prefix you like as long as the namespace URIs match. For this example I chose `fl`.
- Use specific XPath expressions. `/fl:profile/fl:url` is better than `//fl:url`.